# Could the derivative of a function be defined for the values the original function isn't defined at?

Tags: calculus, analysis, logarithms

For instance, The function $f(x)=\ln (x) $ is defined for $x>0$, but $f'(x)=\dfrac{1}{x}$ is defined over the interval $(-\infty ,0)\cup (0,\infty )$. Are there any other functions $f$ other than the natural logarithm function that have this property?
Does this relate to the integral of $\dfrac{1}{x}$ being $\ln |x|$ by any means? How would you explain that for a student that just finished calculus? I mean it's okay to use higher level mathematics but I would most probably be confused, as I haven't yet got into analysis nor did I take any proofs classes.

Comment: How would you define such a derivative?

Comment: Do you mean like, a derivative means slope of tangent to the function?

Comment: Actually on the negative side of $\mathbb{R}$, $\ln(-x)$ is defined and its derivative is $1/x$. So yes, $\ln|x|$ is the answer.

Comment: If you mean that the derivative is the slope of a line tangent to a function at a particular point, then if $f$ is not defined at $a$, how would you define a tangent line at $a$?  Also, I doubt that this is the actual definition of the derivative that you were given.  Typically, the derivative is defined in terms of a limit.  Look at that definition.  How would you define that limit at a point $a$ if $a$ is not in the domain of your function?

Comment: Does this mean that $f'(x)= \dfrac{1} {x}$ is only defined for $x>0$?

Comment: In the particular case you give, the function $x \mapsto 1/x$ is defined for all nonzero real numbers, and is integrable over any interval which does not contain zero.  It's integral is given by $$ \int_{a}^{b} \frac{1}{x} \mathrm{d}x = \begin{cases} \log(b)-\log(a) & \text{if $a,b > 0$, and} \\ \log(-a)-\log(-b) & \text{if $a,b < 0$.} \end{cases} $$ This can be abbreviated to $\log|x|$, which is differentiable everywhere except zero (where it is not defined).

Comment: The statement $f'(x) = 1/x$ is a differential equation.  It has many solutions, which can be summarized (more or less) as
$$ f(x) = \begin{cases}
\log(x) + C & \text{if $x > 0$, and} \\
\log(-x) + D & \text{if $x < 0$,} \end{cases} $$
where $C$ and $D$ are constants.

Comment: So $f(x)= ln(x)$ is just a "special case" of  $\int_{a}^{b} \frac{1}{x} \mathrm{d}x$ where $x>0$ and C = 0?

Comment: It is not clear to me what problem you are trying to solve, hence I don't really know how to answer your question, but... yes?

Comment: Nevermind, I think that answers my question, thank you very much!

Comment: @Dreamer [This answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/4498616/21813) may be of interest. BTW, contrary to your first sentence, $f(x)=\ln(x)$ implies that $f'$ has domain $(0,\infty).$

Answer (score 1):

Given a function $f:X\to Y$ where $X\subseteq\mathbb{R}$ and $Y\subseteq\mathbb{R}$ and $a\in X$ is also an accumulation point of $X$, we define the derivative of $f$ at $a$ as the limit (when it exists):
\begin{align*}
f'(x) = \lim_{x\to a}\frac{f(x) - f(a)}{x - a}
\end{align*}

As you can see, the definition of limit *demands* that $a$ belongs to the domain of $f$.

Having said that, the answer to your question is: no.

Comment: Yes, I guess what he/she wants to ask is after taking the derivative on the domain where it is originally defined, then the new function (forget where it originates from) has a larger domain?